# How to dynamically add multiple textboxes in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var addquestion=$(document.createElement('div')).attr("id",'questionp'+c);
/* ... */
for(var i=1; i<=a.value; i++)
{
  addquestion.after().html('<label>Q'+c+'.&nbsp;'+q+'</label> <br /> <input type="'+sel.value+'" name="fanswer" id="fanswer" value="'+answ+'">'+answ+'');
  addquestion.appendTo("#question");
}
```

This is my for-loop code of JavaScript. I want to multiple text boxes in same div, but it only adds a single textbox.

Comment: what does a.value equal?

Comment: [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) does nothing without an argument.

Comment: You cannot have duplicate `id`'s in a page.

Comment: can only append a single object once, after that you are removing it and replacing it with itself over and over until loop ends

Comment: a.value is the total no. of times I want to print the textboxes on the screen...

Comment: @Blazemonger right, I clarified that

Comment: As @Blazemonger said `.after` is just selecting the element after the `addquestion` DOM element. This element's HTML is then overwritten with the `html` method. Try putting the parameter of `html()` in `after`and remove `.html`. Something like `$("#question").after("yourHTMLString");` should do the trick. However, this is untested ...

Comment: Ok. I will remove ID attribute, It is not that important for the program.

Comment: @Markus You're confusing `.after()` with `.next()`

Comment: @Blazemonger just tried this: `for(var i = 0; i< 3; i++) $("#element").after("<p>hi"+i+"</p>");` and it is working ...

Comment: @Markus I mean, `.after()` doesn't *select* the element after `addquestion`.

Comment: @Blazemonger you are right - my comment is misleading, but the suggestion should work ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're using [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after) incorrectly -- it must have an argument to do anything useful.

Try this instead:

```
for(var i=1; i<=a.value; i++) {
    var addquestion = $('<label>...').appendTo('#question');
}
```

or:

```
for(var i=1; i<=a.value; i++) {
    $('#question').after('<label>...');
}
```

Comment: var addquestion=$(document.createElement('div')).attr("id",'questionp'+c);

Comment: addquestion is as mentioned above.